# java is not working in linux. Why?

Tags: java, linux, java-home

Currently working on `Linux Cinnamon`. I have unistall/removed `Open JDK` from my local drive. Then I checked `java -version` via terminal and gives -

```
$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

After that following the installation guide to install `oracle jdk 8` for `linux`. Then I just checked `java -version` command through [I just unpack `jdk` to `/opt/java`]-

```
$ /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

I set my environment variable `JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_112"` [excluding `bin`] to `/etc/environment` using nano thereafter [from JAVA_HOME setup tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java/175519) -

```
# Java Home
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_112"
export JAVA_HOME
```

and refresh & checked my `JAVA_HOME` as follows -

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_112
```

After these setup while I am trying check `java -version` via command it gives -

```
$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even once you set `$JAVA_HOME`, you still need to add `bin` to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: Is there any problem if put `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"` [with double quote]? -- @Alden

Comment: That works, but does not explain why setting` JAVA_HOME` makes `java` vanish from the `$PATH`.

Comment: @Googly That is not a problem. In fact, it's a good idea (in case `JAVA_HOME` contains spaces, though in your case it doesn't), so I've edited my answer to include quotes.

Comment: @Robert Setting `JAVA_HOME` does not change `PATH` (unless `PATH` is changed as well, as in the answer). Uninstalling OpenJDK before installing Oracle's JDK removed `java` from `PATH`.