# How to skip downloading additional files when the additional files have already been manually downloaded?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have 2 machines - 1a without internet access, and 1b with internet access. I download installation files in 1b and transfer them to 1a. Now, I want to install oracle-java8-installer in 1a. So, I downloaded the file `oracle-java8-installer` in 1b and copied it to 1a. Then, I run the following in 1a:

`sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-installer_8u151-1~webupd8~0_all.deb`

But it tries to download the following file:

`http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz`

and fails, obviously, because it has no internet access.

So, I downloaded the file `jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz` manually in 1b and transferred to 1a. I unzipped/untarred it (and it has no `configure` file inside it, I let it be. If I need to install it, then please let me know how). Then, when I again try to install the `oracle-java8-installer`, it again tries to download this additional file. How do I let the system know that the file has been already downloaded, and point it to its path?

Answer (score 1):

Untarring/unzipping is enough to have Java working on linux (no need to make the web installer find an already download file). Just make sure to point the 'java' on the PATH to your installation folder.

Comment: And how to do that? Is this ok?
`sudo tar zxvf jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/java` and
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java`

Comment: Try this export `PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`
[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322674/java-is-not-working-in-linux-why)

Comment: Yep, thats fine, include @user3382575 line as well to get java's executable on your path.